# Pandas .resample or .asfreq to fill in missing datetime entries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'TransactionId' : pd.Series([633025, 634560],index = ['2018-01-07 22:30:00', '2018-01-08 19:00:00']),
 'Value' : pd.Series([677.06, 677.44], index = ['2018-01-07 22:30:00', '2018-01-08 19:00:00'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.head()
```

Once TransactionId 633025 finishes, values cease recording until the next Transaction begins. I would like to add in a datetime index value every 15 minutes between the two occurrences, with TransactionId of 'NaN', and forward filling the the Value column. I have tried using .resample and .asfreq without any luck; using either with a period of '15min' doesn't modify the dataframe accordingly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make your index a `datetime` and then you can just use `.resample` and then `.ffill`

```
import pandas as pd

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.resample('15min').asfreq()
df['Value'] = df['Value'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
                     TransactionId   Value
2018-01-07 22:30:00       633025.0  677.06
2018-01-07 22:45:00            NaN  677.06
2018-01-07 23:00:00            NaN  677.06
2018-01-07 23:15:00            NaN  677.06
2018-01-07 23:30:00            NaN  677.06 
...
2018-01-08 18:00:00            NaN  677.06
2018-01-08 18:15:00            NaN  677.06
2018-01-08 18:30:00            NaN  677.06
2018-01-08 18:45:00            NaN  677.06
2018-01-08 19:00:00       634560.0  677.44
```

Comment: Ok, so this works perfectly for the way in which I typed out the code in my question; in the actual script, I call read_csv, and I set_index with this line: df.set_index('Timestamp', inplace = True). For some reason, your solution no longer works. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: @thepez87 What is the error you get? Are some of the timestamps invalid or in a format that cannot be automatically parsed? Perhaps try `df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)` before setting the index, that way the index is properly set to a datetime, then you an remove the first line above.

Comment: So I tried setting the Timestamp to datetime before setting it to the index, but that does not help. I'm not actually getting an error, it is just doing nothing, i.e. the shape of the dataframe remains the same after executing the .resample, even though it should greatly increase with the newly filled Values.

Comment: @thepez87 Are you sure you are assigning it back with `df = df.resample()`. By default it will return a copy and if you don't assign it back to `df` you'll never actually change the `DataFrame`